# Why was this an audit in LQPQ?

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits

I just failed the following audit:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/20905964

Granted, this answer is only code, and it has a link that doesn't add anything. It's definitely a bad answer.

However, I've seen multiple discussions that code-only answers should be downvoted, not flagged. The same goes to wrong answers.

So why was this answer flagged and deleted?

Comment: Related https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238647/213575

Comment: Huh, a good audit for once.

Comment: @Will so incredibly unfair, as no-one could have expected it ;)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The link at the end of the answer was a spam link. The answer was completely [plagiarized from another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27769435/4099593), and the spam link was added at the end.

From [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58032/311398):

> If an otherwise valid post contains an apparent spam link and if the bulk of the post is plagiarized from another post or from an offsite source, flag as spam.

Whenever you see an answer in the LQPQ which contains a link at the end, hover over it to see where it points to. If that destination URL seems suspicious, open the post in a new tab, and try to check if it is plagiarized. If it is, then flag it and move on.

Comment: Note that hovering is not easy on phones/tablets.

Comment: One reason why I use FF instead of Chrome, long press shows you the URL.